# Can't break a Palindrome loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, palindrome

I'm just a beginner using Python and have created code to print all the palindrome numbers in a range from 1-1000. However, after my print statement the code just keeps looping and printing the numbers over and over from 1-99. I've tried using break; after the print(i) statement, but it then causes the console to print 1 and ****Palindromes*** in a loop instead of the palindrome numbers. Any suggestions to break out of the loop?`

```
    pi = 3.14159
area = 0

def areaSquare(squareWidth):
    return squareWidth * squareWidth

def areaCircle(radius):
    return pi *(radius * radius)

   
def menu():     #Creat the menu for user to see
    print("\nCalculations")
    print("1. Calculate area of a square\n2. Calculate the area of a circle\n3. Display palindromes up to 1,000\n4. Exit programme.")


menu()  # call the menu
option = int(input("Enter an option: "))

while option != 4:   #create a loop
    if option == 1:
            print("***Area of a square***") 
            squareWidth = float(input("Enter width of square(cm): "))
            print("The area of the square of width ",squareWidth, "cm = ", areaSquare(squareWidth), "cm squared")
            menu()
            option = int(input("Enter an option: "))
    elif option == 2:
            print("***Area of a circle***");
            radius = float(input("Enter radius of circle(cm): "))
            print("The area of a circle of " , radius , "cm = ", areaCircle(radius), " round")
            menu()
            option = int(input("Enter an option: "))
    elif option == 3:
           for i in range(1, 1000): 
              if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
                  print(i,)
    else:   
        print("Invlid entry, please select a number between 1 and 4.")

        menu()
        option = int(input("Enter an option: "))     

print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: It works fine if you just remove the indentation from `for i in range(1, 1000):` line. Please share a screenshot of the output that you are getting.

Comment: For me, it also works with proper indention. I would recommend replacing `str(i)` and `i` by `n` in the last two lines, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

```python
print("**Palindromes***");
for i in range(1, 1000): 
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        print(i,)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw5CoAwEAB7X7FYJYtCgl3EP9iLRcBrQTeypvH18ZxqYGD2My6Bq5R2IY4qR2z9SjxI2MYDEXNdZ1MQICAG8TyPyhZgjTHaQQY3NMERRZGGpvmtc660vXvzw/emQqd0AQ)

This should do the trick. I think you have an outer loop that is causing the indent in your code, which is why your loop is not breaking.

Comment: Ahh, yes, could possibly be the outer while loop? Here is the full code

Comment: @CherylO'Hagan if my answer solved your problem, can you please accept it and close this question? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I changed the while loop to an if statement, and was able to get the loop to break!